# YouTrack Scrum Boards

Tags: scrum, youtrack, scrumboard

i created a YouTrack project, based on Scrum. The tool generated two boards (projekt management and projekt development). What is the purpose of two boards?

- separate sprint backlog (done, to do)?
- or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Project Management Board** is built to track the development of major features and long-term strategic planning. This board represents the relationship between epics and user stores. Only issues with these types are displayed on the board.

The **Project Development Board** is built for planning and managing incremental improvements in a series of sprints. This board represents the relationship between user stories and tasks.

More details about this template [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Scrum-Project-Template.html#scrum-project-template-agile-boards).

Comment: Is the "Project Management Board" an idea from YouTrack or is it impacted from other Docs/..?